# Removing a line, plus drop the comma of the last line with a matching pattern

Tags: awk, sed

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qalnk`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `qalnk` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_deleted` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by_user_ap_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordering` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_for_deselect_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK6661B19F393DFCD` (`expression_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B195182DDCD` (`question_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B195742A56B` (`expression_for_deselect_id`),
  KEY `idx_qlnk_nswrd` (`answer_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B19126D878D` (`answer_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B1975B33071` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK6661B19126D878D` FOREIGN KEY (`answer_id`) REFERENCES `ans` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK6661B1975B33071` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `apobj` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

My goal is to drop all constraints from a database, so I would like to have simple code search for the word "CONSTRAINT" and drop the line

I tried to use sed

```
sed '/\s*CONSTRAINT/d' ~/Downloads/dump.sql > ~/ouput.sql
```

but there are all these tailing comma that are left behind because of CONSTRAINTS being the last statement.  I don't mind if it awk, sed, or some common tools.

The desired output is

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qalnk`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `qalnk` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_deleted` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by_user_ap_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordering` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_for_deselect_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK6661B19F393DFCD` (`expression_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B195182DDCD` (`question_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B195742A56B` (`expression_for_deselect_id`),
  KEY `idx_qlnk_nswrd` (`answer_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B19126D878D` (`answer_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B1975B33071` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: Little modification of yours solution:
sed '/CONSTRAINT/d' ~/Downloads/dump.sql > ~/ouput.sql

Comment: @josifoski: While your suggestion is truly the simpler (non-redundant) _equivalent_ of the OP's `sed` command, the better alternative in this context is probably `sed '/^\s*CONSTRAINT /d'` - i.e., to _anchor_ the expression at the start of a line (note that the use of `\s` assumes _GNU_ `sed`; with _mandatory_ preceding whitespace you'd need `sed '/^\s\+CONSTRAINT /d'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else just use awk. Here's GNU awk for multi-char RS and the `\s` abbreviation for `[[:space:]]`:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/,\s*CONSTRAINT[^\n,]+/,"")}1' file
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qalnk`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `qalnk` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_deleted` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by_user_ap_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordering` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expression_for_deselect_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK6661B19F393DFCD` (`expression_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B195182DDCD` (`question_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B195742A56B` (`expression_for_deselect_id`),
  KEY `idx_qlnk_nswrd` (`answer_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B19126D878D` (`answer_id`),
  KEY `FK6661B1975B33071` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

For a POSIX-only solution (see comments below from @mklement0):

```
awk -v RS=$(printf '\3') -v ORS= '{gsub(/,[[:space:]]*CONSTRAINT[^\n,]+/,"")}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack - use (GNU) `awk` to shift trailing `,`s to the start of subsequent lines first followed by a `sed` delete.

```
awk -v RS= '{gsub(/,\n/, "\n,"); print}'  ~/Downloads/dump.sql | 
sed '/\s*CONSTRAINT/d' > ~/ouput.sql
```

This gives me the following, which should be valid SQL

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qalnk`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `qalnk` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
,  `answer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
,  `date_deleted` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
,  `deleted_by_user_ap_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL
,  `expression_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
,  `expression_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
,  `ordering` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
,  `question_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
,  `expression_for_deselect_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
,  KEY `FK6661B19F393DFCD` (`expression_id`)
,  KEY `FK6661B195182DDCD` (`question_id`)
,  KEY `FK6661B195742A56B` (`expression_for_deselect_id`)
,  KEY `idx_qlnk_nswrd` (`answer_id`)
,  KEY `FK6661B19126D878D` (`answer_id`)
,  KEY `FK6661B1975B33071` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Answer (score 0):

search for any line that has the expression "CONSTRAINT" and delete line and the `,` before that line.

```
sed -e '/.*/{
N
s/,\n.*CONSTRAINT//g}' -e '/.*CONSTRAINT.*/d' my_file
```

Answer (score -1):

A *single-pass* `sed` solution requires that all input lines be read *at once*, similar to [Ed Morton's helpful `awk` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27576752/45375):

A ***GNU* `sed` solution**:

```
sed -zr 's/,\n\s*CONSTRAINT\s+[^\n,]+//g' file
```

- `-z` uses NUL (null bytes) as the input line separator, and since the are no embedded NULs in the input, the entire contents of `file` is read into the pattern space at once.
- `-r` enables *extended* regular expressions (modern syntax, extended features).
- The regex removes all `CONSTRAINT` lines, including the `,\n` from the preceding line, which leaves the syntax of the enclosing `CREATE TABLE` statement intact.

A ***BSD* (macOS) `sed` solution** is, unfortunately, much more cumbersome:

The BSD `sed` version is missing many of GNU's (nonstandard) convenience features, which makes the solution more painful.
BSD `sed` offers only a few extensions to the POSIX standard, but a notable one is the ability to use so-called extended regular expressions.

```
sed -E ':a
$!{N;ba
}
s/,\n([[:blank:]]*CONSTRAINT[[:blank:]]+[[:print:][:blank:]]+\n)+/\
/g' file
```

- `-E` - similar to GNU `sed`'s `-r` - enables *extended* regular expressions.
- `:a\n$!{N;b\na}` is a common `sed` idiom that reads the entire input at once:

  - `:a` defines a label to jump to.
  - `$!` matches  every line *but* (`!`) the last (`$`)
  - `{N;ba};` reads the next line into the pattern space (input buffer to operate on), then branches (`b`) to label `a` (`:a`).
  - In other words: This reads all lines into the pattern space, which is what the subsequent commands then operate on (`s`, in this case).
- Note the required newlines, both to terminate branch labels and branching commands, and (in escaped form) in the replacement command.
- It *is* possible to cram this into a single line by using multiple `-e` options, but that makes the command less readable.
- Note the use of verbose POSIX character classes such as `[[:blank:]]`, because shortcut classes such as `\s` aren't supported.
- In particular, while `\n` can be matched in the regex *in principle*, it is inexplicably *not* recognized inside a *character class*. Thus, `[^\n]` must be emulated with `[[:print:][:blank:]]` -- `[:blank:]` is added to also match tab chars., which are not considered *printable* chars; (`\t` can't be used inside char. classes either).

Comment: This answer is now being discussed on [Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426495/45375).